# System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled - AWS file services

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, windows-10, hyper-v

I was trying to resolve an issue with getting/uploading files.
The root cause of error was file service not working in the test server.
But is working in the my local pc.

Trying to find out what is blocking or restricting this service to be run on the test server.

here is the exception thrown:

```
{"":["System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFinishSendAsyncError(Exception e, 
CancellationTokenSource cts)  
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, 
HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)   
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)  
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_1`1. 
<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop() 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task)
at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.DownloadStringContent(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout, IWebProxy proxy)  
at Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.GetItems(String relativeOrAbsolutePath, Int32 tries, Boolean slurp)
at Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.get_IAMSecurityCredentials()   
at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()   
at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentials() 
at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentialsAsync()  
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)   
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)  
at Sms.Office.PacmsTri.Services.File.FileStorage.WriteFileAsync(Stream file, String contentType, String filename, CancellationToken token) in C:\\agent\\_work\\1\\s\\source\\PacmsTri\\Services\\File\\FileStorage.cs:line 57
at Sms.Office.PacmsTri.Services.ReportServer.UploadAndGetFileStorageIdAsync(Stream outputStream, String fileName, String generatedfilename) in C:\\agent\\_work\\1\\s\\source\\PacmsTri\\Services\\ReportServer.cs:line 161 
at Sms.Office.PacmsTri.Areas.Pacms.Controllers.PurchaseShipListController.EstimateCondition_Send(String qNo, Int32 orderByNum, String CcNames, String CcEmails, String ToSupplier, CancellationToken token) in C:\\agent\\_work\\1\\s\\source\\PacmsTri\\Areas\\Pacms\\Controllers\\PurchaseShipListOrder.cs:line 2792"]}
```

Comment: Most likely a timeout issue. Try setting the `HttpClient` timeout property higher.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by setting the environment variables for the AWS class that was missing in the system. Many thanks.

Comment: which environment variables please? I am facing the same issue